# Yanked USB Key During Move

Tags: linux, backup, fedora, usb

I'm using Fedora 17.

I was backing up some files to a USB key.  I was foolish and used the Move command instead of copy, and before the directory I was moving completed I accidentally yanked the usb key from the port.

The USB key is now empty, and the directory I moved is no longer on my hard drive.

Does anyone know if I can recover from this?  Is there a temporary directory that houses moved files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is format of your USB and HDD partition ? You mentioned that, It's Fedora 17. So partition will be ext3/ext4.

You can use photorec for recover files. Check bellow link for step by step process.

http://blog.adminnote.com/2010/08/deleted-file-recovery-in-liunx-photorec.html